# Cron job and Access Denied function

Tags: users, cron

I have a custom module which implements  `hook_node_view()` and checks certain conditions to decide whether a user can view the content or not. The code snippet is:

```
    if( ! user_is_logged_in() && $node->type == "abc") {
        drupal_access_denied(); 
        module_invoke_all('exit'); 
        exit(); 
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

The code works fine for me but the problem occurs when drupal's cron runs as `Anonymous` user. The only message I get is `Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running.` Could you please give me your suggestion to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_node_view()` shouldn't be used for access checks, there's [`hook_node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) for that sort of situation:

```
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if ($type == 'abc' && $op == 'view') {
    return $account->uid > 0;
  }
}
```

That'll handle the access check for the node gracefully, and shouldn't stop cron running halfway through.

Comment: I also wanted to check if there are certain fields marked or not i.e. only deny if the node has taxonomy term 'A grade' else allow the user to view the content or node.

Comment: No problem there, you can do that from `hook_node_access()` too. Making access checks, and invoking a 403 from as late on as the `_view()` hook, isn't the best idea is all

Comment: But how will the hook differentiate between corn running as anonymous and normal anonymous user.

Comment: It won't...cron is always run as an anonymous. See `drupal_cron_run()`, line 5200ish of /includes/common.inc: `// Force the current user to anonymous to ensure consistent permissions on cron runs. $original_user = $GLOBALS['user']; $GLOBALS['user'] = drupal_anonymous_user();`. There's nothing to differentiate the context the bootstrap happens in, Drupal just knows that it's bootstrapped and has some env variables available